# The difference between = and ==

Tags: java

What is the difference between = true and == true in :

```
 void startengine(){
   if ( enginestat == true )
       System.out.println("The engine is already on ");
 else { enginestat = true;
       System.out.println("The engine is now on");
       }
```

Comment: You really ought to go read some of the basic tutorials about [assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) and [equality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

Comment: i think you got confused with the "else" and "enginestat=true;" being on the same line. they are actually two different statements.

Answer (score 5):

`==` outputs a boolean that represents whether the two expressions are equal. (the boolean is equal to true or false).

`=` assigns the value of the expression on the right side to the variable on the left.

Answer (score 1):

`=` Is an assignment operator (sets a variable). `==` Is a comparison operator (compares a variable to another value/variable).

Example:

```
int x = 1; //setting x to 1
int y = 2; //setting y to 2
if(x == y){ //comparing the two
    //do something
} else {
  //do something else
}
```

The above code uses `int` variables but the same can be done with doubles, strings, booleans, etc.

In your code:

```
void startengine(){
  if ( enginestat == true ) //You are checking if enginestat is true
    System.out.println("The engine is already on ");
  else { enginestat = true; //You are setting enginestat to true
   System.out.println("The engine is now on");
   }
```

For more:

[Assignment operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

[Comparison operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

Answer (score 0):

= is the assignment operator. It assigns a value to variable.

```
int x = 5;
String name = "james";
```

== is used for comparison.

```
if (x == 5){ ... }
```

But if you use the assignment operator in the if statement it will always return true;

```
if (x=17){
//this part will always be executed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`==` is used to determine equality.

`=` is a load operation, used to assign a value.